# Disconnect server SSH and Terminal. Error Plymouth command failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, system-administration

I found same theme here [Mountall: disconnected from plymouth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883516/mountall-disconnected-from-plymouth)

But here is not answer.This error appeared suddenly, and after I can not connect to root user terminal and SSH Protocol.

In terminal I get message: Plymouth command failed. Disconnected...
Why as it happened and how fix, because I lost control server Ubuntu. Now I can work only in single user mode.
Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like you try to setup a graphical environment when logging in via ssh? And as root user? Don't! What happens if you try another user account?

Comment: Yes, now i work only under root user. At hosting panel there is window terminal, when i open it, i get error Plymouth. And also connect across SSH - gives me disconnect. Now i change mode on single use and entered in terminal how as root. But only in mode only read.

Comment: You should _never_ login from remote using the `root` account. Under normal circumstances such login should actually be disabled inside the ssh configuration. Also you should _never_ start a graphical environment using the `root` account. Instead you should _always_ login using a normal, non privilidged user account and only run those commands as user `root` that actually _require_ such permissions. You can use the `sudo` utility in a very convenient form for this. The reason is that both things open security issues. And you certainly do not want that for your own system, do you?

Comment: Yes, i know, but now need to resolve this problem after will create some users with low privileges. I want know reason this problem and how to fix, because it is strangely

Comment: You caanot solve that using ssh. You need to have access to the boot process, either via a physical console or a virtual one. You can boot the system in single user mode and runlevel 3 (non graphical). That way you should be able to modify the system setup.

Comment: Thank you. Now I connected at terminal how as you said. What i must confugure or setup fox resolve?

Comment: Well 1. create a user account and store the ssh key for the login, 2. configure the sudo configuration file `/etc/sudoers` (see the manual pages: `man sudo` and `man sudoers`) and 3. modify your system such that it does not boot into a graphical mode if you only use it from remote.

Comment: Ok, i created separate from root user with password. But i dont understand step 2 and 3. How it will help me?

Comment: Step 2. helps you with executing single commands with root permissions without having to actually switch your id: `sudo touch somefile` will create a file "somefile" using root permissions as an example, although you execute that command as a normal user. The sudoers file helps with fine tuning that. Step 3. referred to my impression, that you also boot the system into a graphical mode right away. That does make sense for a desktop workstation, but never for a server. you can change that, since you should not use a graphical environment on a server. you actually shouldn't even install one.